# Error System.NullReferenceException: Al recibir valor de ViewModel en Vista desde Acción de Controlador

Tags: mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Tengo un error al mostrar el valor de un campo que pertenece a un modelo y que paso desde el controlador a la vista:

Aquí mi controlador:

```
    public ActionResult ValidaAplicacion(AplicacionViewModel mAplicacion)
    {
        RespuestaViewModel oRA = new RespuestaViewModel();
        oRA.resultado = 1;
        try
        {
            using (AccesoEntities db = new AccesoEntities())
            {
                var lst = (from ca in db.catalogo_aplicacion
                           join ce in db.catalogo_estatus on ca.id_estatus equals ce.id
                           where ca.id == mAplicacion.id_aplicacion
                           select new { ca.id, ca.cnombre_aplicacion, ca.curl, ca.id_estatus }).FirstOrDefault();
                if (lst == null)
                {
                    oRA.resultado = 5;
                    oRA.mensaje = "No encontre relación del ID que enviastes con ninguna aplicación registrada. Por favor verifica ID enviado."; // Si se recibe un ID que no exista de la aplicación
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (lst.id_estatus)
                    {
                        case 2:
                            oRA.resultado = 2;
                            oRA.mensaje = "Lamentamos los inconvenientes causados, esta aplicación esta INACTIVA TEMPORALMENTE, para mayores informes consulte con el COORDINADOR y/o RESPONSABLE de este PORTAL.";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            oRA.resultado = 3;
                            oRA.mensaje = "Lamentamos los inconvenientes causados, la Aplicación se ENCUENTRA en proceso de ACTUALIZACIÓN y/o MANTENIMIENTO, consulte más tarde...";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            oRA.resultado = 4;
                            oRA.mensaje = "Le informamos que la Aplicación se encuentra DADA DE BAJA, para mayores informes consulte con el COORDINADOR y/o RESPONSABLE de este PORTAL .";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            oRA.resultado = 5;
            oRA.mensaje = "Esto no me lo esperaba... ha ocurrido un error:" + ex.ToString();
            throw;
        }
        if (oRA.resultado > 1)
        {
            **return RedirectToAction("Mensaje", "Home", oRA);**
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

Al llamar a la vista **Mensaje** del controlador **Home**, enviándole el **ViewModel** a la vista donde lo recibo así:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
**@model Login.Models.ViewModels.RespuestaViewModel**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../assets/images/favicon.png">
    <title>Autentificación de Usuarios - Versión 2.0. </title>
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
</head>
<body class="fix-header card-no-border">
    <section id="wrapper" class="error-page">
        <div class="error-box">
            <div class="error-body text-center">
                <h1 class="text-info">:-/ Ups !</h1>
                <h3 class="text-uppercase">¡ NOTIFICACIÓN !</h3>
                <p class="text-muted mt-4 mb-4">**@Model.mensaje**</p>
                <a href="www.inicio.net" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded waves-effect waves-light mb-5">Ir a UZH</a>
            </div>
            <footer class="footer text-center">© 2019 Departamento de Sistemas de Información</footer>
        </div>
    </section>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js")
</body>
</html>
```

Le llamo desde el navegador con la url enviándole el parámetro: **http://localhost:63694/Aplicacion/ValidaAplicacion?id_aplicacion=2**

Justo en **@Modelo.mensaje** me indica:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida
>   como instancia de un objeto.
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get devolvió null.

Este es el ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Login.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class RespuestaViewModel
    {
        public int resultado { get; set; }  
        public object data { get; set; } 
        public string mensaje { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Que estaré haciendo mal ?. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola. Tienes alguna **Acción** que se llame **Mensaje()** en tu Controlador?, si es así, edita la pregunta e indica el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio parece que estás confundiendo los términos:

**RedirectToAction()** lo que hace es redirigir hacia una **Acción** determinada de un **Controlador** determinado.

En tu caso `return RedirectToAction("Mensaje", "Home", oRA);`, estaría pasando el "flujo de control" a la **Acción** `Mensaje()` del **Controlador** `HomeController`, y **NO** a la **Vista** `Mensaje.cshtml`.

Para devolver la Vista `Mensaje.cshtml`, debes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
return View("Mensaje", oRA);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Por otra parte, **si realmente tienes** una **Acción** llamada `Mensaje()` en el `HomeController`, esta debería recibir un parámetro del tipo `RespuestaViewModel`.

El código debería ser así:

```
    public ActionResult Mensaje(RespuestaViewModel respuestaViewModel)
    {
        return View("Mensaje", respuestaViewModel);
    }
```

De esta manera si podría funcionar tu ejemplo, pero la redirección (**RedirectToAction**) debería ser de esta manera:

```
        return RedirectToAction("Mensaje", "Home", new
        {
            resultado = oRA.resultado,
            data = oRA.data,
            mensaje = oRA.mensaje,
        });
```

El problema esta en que no puedes enviar desde el **RedirectToAction** un **objeto complejo** en el `RouteValues`, debes hacerlo mediante un **objeto anónimo** con las mismas propiedades del **Modelo** `RespuestaViewModel`.

Comment: Gracias Rafael he actualizado el codigo con Return View() fue más simple en el resultado.